# How can I build string matching tree from array of regex-es?

Tags: c, regex, automata, search-tree

I've got dynamic(sometime changes) array of regular expressions, for example URL path structure:

- **`/(home)?$`** -> home view
- **`/news/(index)?$`** ->
- **`/news/([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/?$`** -> news article view`( arg_1 )`
- **`/news/([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/reply_to_comment\?(.*)`** -> news comment reply view`( arg 1, arg 2 )`
- **`/(.+)`** -> 404 view `( arg 1 )`

**If there are collisions, the first expression is winner**. For example last expression matches everything, but in case, that no expression before matched it. Or /news/index can by matched as article, but index is before article expression, so it wins.

I'd like to build **state machine/expression tree**, which I can use to match any strings in **O(n)** time, where **n** is length of string is being matched, i.e. I don't care about time needed to build that tree, but I want to have same speed of matching regardless of number of expressions.

Or at least for "limited" regex, supporting only: `+`, `*`, `?`, `[]`, `[^ ]`, `()`, `$`.
Treat every expression `expr` not starting with `^` as if it were written as `^expr`.

Comment: If the first match always wins, you need to move `reply_to_comment` one line up, and `(home)?` and `(index)?` much lower. I'd loose the `?` expressions and test from first to last character.

Comment: Yes, you're correct. I've editted expressions.

Comment: (After thinking about this for a while) It seems to me you have to convert your match strings into a binary tree format, so you can use a single state to determine the 'matching' of any character from start to finish only once. You could create this once by hand, but adding or changing a phrase is lots of work. I'm going to think a bit longer on how to convert a list of GREPs to a state machine.